# Modified time from user's input bash script

Tags: bash, date, search

I am new with shell script programming and I want to create a searching program using shell script. When user enter the modified time, it will show a list of all files which have modified time less than the user's input. But nothing appear. What have I messed up?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter a date:"
read -r numdate
result4=$(find -type f -mtime -"$numdate" -print)
echo "$result4"
```

Comment: Try [\[ shellcheck \]](http://www.shellcheck.net/)

Comment: I tried it before no issues detected but the script shows no result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below will work

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter day/s : " numdays
echo "Files which were modified $numdays days ago"
result4=$(find -type f -mtime "$numdays")
echo "$result4"
```

**Notes:**

1. You could use read prompt here ie `-p` option.
2. find manpage says the `mtime` expects days as an integer:

   > -mtime n
   >                 File's data was last modified n*24 hours ago.

Comment: tkank you so much I found the problem. However the `-` before `$numdate` is used for imply the modified day less than the day user enter, for example `find -type f -mtime -50 -print`.

Comment: @Windy764 : You're right . I will remove the first point from the notes

Comment: So how then does this fix the OP's problem?

Comment: @tripleee : I guess it was the the way op entered `numdays` . I guessed that because they used `read -r numdate` in the question